# how to run multiple mysql queries in one time

Tags: mysql

I have two queries in MySQL

```
select count(activity_id) from asd where ico_detail_id = '5a673c68a895200d64cd6a18' and activity_id = 1 and is_active = 1;

select count(activity_id) from asd where ico_detail_id = '5a673c68a895200d64cd6a18' and activity_id = 2 and is_active = 1;
```

I want to run these two queries at one time using the procedure or something else.

Help needed. Thanxx in adv

Comment: Use union queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregate,

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN activity_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) activity_id_1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN activity_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) activity_id_2
FROM    bulltoken.ico_vote 
WHERE   ico_detail_id = '5a673c68a895200d64cd6a18' 
        AND is_active = 1;
```

This will display:

```
---------------+---------------
activity_id_1  +  activity_id_2
---------------+---------------
10             +  20          
---------------+---------------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(activity_id) from bulltoken.ico_vote where ico_detail_id = '5a673c68a895200d64cd6a18' and activity_id = 1 and is_active = 1;
UNION
select count(activity_id) from bulltoken.ico_vote where ico_detail_id = '5a673c68a895200d64cd6a18' and activity_id = 2 and is_active = 1;
```